# Variable does not exist when trying to access 1st element of list

Tags: apex, json, compile-error, typecast

Below i the code :

```
Map<String,Object> poVals = 

    (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(POResponse); 
     system.debug('poVals' +poVals);
     lstPODetails = (List<object>)poVals.get('purchaseOrders'); 
     system.debug('lstPODetails' +lstPODetails);
     String poFormat = lstPODetails.get(0).FORMAT;
```

when trying to access a variable from 1st element of list in the last line, it says that variable doesn't exist : FORMAT
What do you think is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

The `Object` type does not contain any attributes or methods by default. You need to cast it to a concrete type to access any properties on a particular instance. For instance, if you had a `PurchaseOrderWrapper` class defined as below, you would deserialize into a `List<PurchaseOrderWrapper>` instead of `List<Object>`.

```
public with sharing class PurchaseOrderWrapper
{
    final String format;
}
```

Instead of:

```
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
List<Object> data = (List<Object>)response.get('purchaseOrders');
```

Use:

```
List<PurchaseOrderWrapper> data = 
    (List<PurchaseOrderWrapper>)response.get('purchaseOrders');
```

You can read more about the `Object` type in the `Apex Developer Guide` under [Primitive Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> Any data type that is supported in Apex. Apex supports primitive data types (such as Integer), user-defined custom classes, the sObject generic type, or an sObject specific type (such as Account). All Apex data types inherit from Object.
>
> You can cast an object that represents a more specific data type to its underlying data type. For example:
>
> ```
> Object obj = 10;
> // Cast the object to an integer.
> Integer i = (Integer)obj;
> System.assertEquals(10, i);
> ```
>
> The next example shows how to cast an object to a user-defined type—a custom Apex class named MyApexClass that is predefined in your organization.
>
> ```
> Object obj = new MyApexClass();
> // Cast the object to the MyApexClass custom type.
> MyApexClass mc = (MyApexClass)obj;
> // Access a method on the user-defined class.
> mc.someClassMethod();
> ```